# In airflow with dbt, why are tasks consuming so many resources if it just sends queries to snowflake

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I have an airflow deployment on AWS MWAA, and we have a dbt model which we call from a DAG. The queries on dbt are launched against a snowflake warehouse which makes the computations. However, we have a task that spans 60 concurrent subtasks, the task basically is a for loop that formats a query to change parameter.

Those 60 concurrent tasks are showing us that airflow's resources should grow by a lot. I understand concurrency has an implication in resources. However, in this case it's going up to multiple times more workers and RAM than if it was not parallel.

My question is: If snowflake warehouse is the one doing the actual processing and airflow is just the orchestrator, why is airflow demanding such increase in resources if it's just sending queries? Or am I wrong at something here? How does airflow needs multiple times more RAM to manage 60 queries that it sent to snowflake?

Comment: It shall not. While Airflow runs tasks in separate processes. which means it will load every task as a sub process. That might takes quite some memory.

Comment: But if the tasks are meant to just submit queries to snowflake, why are they consuming so much RAM? I mean if I would manually create 60 cronjobs that each just submit a query to snowflake they wouldn't need more than 5GB of RAM, since it's not like snowflake will answer back with the data (or would it and that's why so much RAM? )

Comment: I guess a live connection towards snowflake through dbt could take something like 100Mb. As my snowflake test account just expired so I could not get the exact number. Based on your situation, I recommend first check out those task still keep one separate process running. If so limit down the amount of task submit to snowflake might be a good choice. As snowflake wont be able to finish so many task at once anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My guessing is although airflow only submit the tasks, but since the task result has been return from data sources, and they will be reused in the following tasks, that's why you can see the RAM usage increased.

It is similar with a multiple threads downloading process, the difference is downloading is write data into the disk, but the airflow has no persist steps (maybe it has), so all data which will be reused has to store in your RAM.

Comment: Is there something to tell airflow to not persist any data or wait for any data to return that it needs to save? Or some way to see what data airflow is saving?

Comment: It depends on the logic in your airflow task, airflow is just a orchestration tools.